# How to create SortedSet (e.g. TreeSet) for elements of type BitSet

Tags: java, classcastexception, comparable, bitset

I have a number `(power(2,k))` of BitSet objects and I want to store them in a `SortedSet`. I use the code:

```
Set <BitSet> S= new TreeSet<>();
```

However, I am getting this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.BitSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

How do I implement comparable interface? Or is there any other way to sort these elements of type `BitSet`?

Comment: What meaning do you intend for `compareTo()`? Cardinality?

Comment: The intention is to sort this collection of BitSet objects and so compareTo.

Comment: The problem is `BitSet` does not implement `compareTo`, so you have to define your own ordering of `BitSet`. What is your desired ordering?

Comment: I need ascending order of these BitSet objects. Is there any other way out than using TreeSet?

Comment: Define ascending order.

Comment: 00011 < 00100 < 00110

Comment: Ok, now write a Comparator<BitSet> describing that logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to use a `TreeSet`.

1. Have it contain objects that implement `Comparable`
2. Have a custom `Comparator` object that compares the elements of your `TreeSet`.

Since you want to have your `TreeSet` contain `BitSet`s, and `BitSet` does not implement `Comparable`, you need to give your `TreeSet` a custom `Comparator`. How you implement that `Comparator` is up to you.

```
SortedSet<BitSet> s = new TreeSet<BitSet>(new CustomBitSetComparator());
s.add(bitSet1);
s.add(bitSet2);
//etc ...
```

The Comparator may look something like this

```
class CustomBitSetComparator implements Comparator<BitSet>{
    int compare(BitSet a, BitSet b) {
        if(a == b){
            return 0;
        } else if(a == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if(b == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if(a.equals(b)) {
            return 0;
        } else if(a.length() > b.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if(b.lenght() > a.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
               if(a.get(i) != b.get(i)) {
                   if(a.get(i)) {
                      return 1;
                   } else {
                      return -1;
                   }
                }
             }
             return 0;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The input to this SortedSet is coming through other part of programs. So what I receive is a stream of BitSet objects which I have to collect and sort and process. **new CustomBitSetComparator()** can't be implemented here!

Comment: The `CustomBitSetComparator()` does not contain any `BitSet`s. It compares them. It implemnts `Comparator<BitSet>`, which has a function `compare(BitSet, BitSet)` that the `TreeSet` uses to compare the incoming `BitSet`s. You have to write this class yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert them to BigIntegers (O(N)) and use a TreeSet. Otherwise you will have to write yourself a Comparator, which in the nature of things will run excruciatingly slowly, as you can see from other answers. I would also consider using PriorityQueue instead of a Set.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you want to put BitSet in a treeSet, while a workaround is to create a **wrapper class** which implements **Comparable** interface.

```
Public class CustomComparableBitSet implements Comparable{
   private BitSet bs;

   public int compareTo(T o){
      //your comparison logic goes here.
   }
}
```

then in the client code, add **instance of CustomComparableBitSet** into **treeset**.

Comment: I have these thousands of BitSet objects and I need to sort them first to process further (The processing requires them to be ascending order). So I thought TreeSet would be best data structure. If there is any other way out, please let me know.

Comment: Ok if you have thousands of BitSet objects, creating wrapper objects might not be a good idea, because it will bring in some memory overhead. How about extends BitSet class and implements Comparable.
public class CustomeComparableBitSet<T> extends BitSet implements Comparable<T> {

 public int compareTo(T arg0) {
  int i = 0;
  // TODO change i based on your comparison logic
  return i;
 }
}