# Creating a sorted Set

Tags: java

Is there a way to sort a `Set`?

I have a `Set` of double and I am looking for a way to sort them.
I understand it is very easy using List, but something using `Set` is getting a bit tricky to me.

Any inputs would be great help.

Comment: TreeSet? Explore the java api. Simple search will give you this answer

Answer (score 10):

You should put them into `TreeSet`. `TreeSet` is a `SortedSet` implementation which orders the elements according to the natural ordering.

`TreeSet` accepts objects which implements `Comparable` which defines the sort order. `Double` objects can be put into `TreeSet` since they implement `Comparable`

Comment: and TreeSet on println prints inorder traversal.

Comment: TreeSet also accepts a Comparator, so you don't need to implement Comparable in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted set:

```
return new TreeSet(setIWantSorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

1. Use [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)
2. Use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

[SortedSet is an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/) The detailed hierarchy is mentioned in the link

To use TreeSet Here's a link for an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330340/how-to-create-sortedset-e-g-treeset-for-elements-of-type-bitset)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `TreeSet` is an implementation of `SortedSet` and that `SortedSet` is just an interace.

Comment: @zEro : yup I was adding info